# Eclipse PyDev: setting breakpoints in site-packages source

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I am debugging a problem in Django with **Pydev**.
I **can set breakpoint** in my django **project code** with out a problem.
However I **can't set breakpoints** in the **Django library source code** (in site-packages).

The PyDev debugger user interface in this case **simply does nothing when I click** to set the breakpoint and does not break at that location when I run the debugger.

Am I missing some PyDev configuration? In other debuggers I have used, this behavior indicates a problem relating the debug information with the source code.
Any ideas on next steps would be a help.

I also have the **site-packages** configured in PyDev to be in my **PYTHONPATH**

I am using Eclipse on Max OS X if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the django source to your pydev project, and set it as a source folder?  When you say you can't set breakpoints, does that mean that the debugger doesn't stop on those lines or won't step into django code, or that you literally can't double-click on the line number to set a break?

Comment: In means both, double clicking does not set a breakpoint and it does not break while debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you imported the Django source as a project? To do that you just create a new PyDev project and set it's location to the Django source folder.

Comment: I did not realize that you needed to add it as a project.
I thought having it in the PYTHONPATH was good enough.
Good to know.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hey, this is timely! Eric Moritz just announced the release of an interesting new way to debug views using pdb called [django-viewtools](http://eric.themoritzfamily.com/2009/02/17/announcing-django-viewtools/).

Answer (score 0):

You might try instead the Python debugger pdb in this instance.

This is a helpful link describing it: http://www.ferg.org/papers/debugging_in_python.html

Answer (score 0):

PyDev 1.5.5 seems to have an issue with Eclipse.  Uninstall 1.5.5 and install the 1.5.4 version